# How to allow infinite maximum execution time for PHP under WAMP?

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have a script which is designed to work on an endless task. I would like to allow it to run forever, but it stops when the maximum execution timeout of 30 seconds is reached. I can set

```
max_execution_time = 3000
```

or something like that, but whatever limit I do it will be a finite limit. How can I make sure that my script is running for infinity?

Comment: Don't run it in the webserver? It isn't a good idea to do that for long running jobs anyway.- run it from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it to 0. according to :

[The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)